# how to remove the record from gridview when i click on delete button in vb.net?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

how to remove the record from gridview when i click on delete button in vb.net ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gridview has an event called 'RowDeleting' which you can use to handle Delete events.
For example:

```
Private Sub gridview_RowDeleting(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewDeleteEventArgs) Handles gridview.RowDeleting

   '' Handle your delete here and rebind your datasource if needed

End Sub
```